# Replace All in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code in Excel VBA where I am required to replace all the numbers in a column with a "-".

```
18
-
-
-
6%
11%
-
-
83%
```

I am able to select the whole column, but only able to replace 18 with a -.
Please suggest me what I could possibly be doing wrong or add up in my code to replace everything in a column

```
For x = 1 To BannerColumn - 1
    If (Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn).Offset(0, x) < 30) Then
    row1 = Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn + x).Row
    col1 = Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn + x).Column


    Set abc = Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn + x).End(xlDown)
    row2 = abc.Row
    col2 = abc.Column

    Range(Cells(row1, col1), Cells(row2, col2)).Select
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
   End If
Next x
```

I am using the above code. My Requirement is I am having a banner of 31 columns, and I need to find each banner point less than 30, and replace that column with -.

Comment: *Please suggest me what I could possibly be doing wrong* - That is hard to do considering we don't the code you are using. Please update your post with the actual code. [ask]

Comment: For x = 1 To BannerColumn - 1
    If (Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn).Offset(0, x) < 30) Then
    row1 = Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn + x).Row
    col1 = Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn + x).Column
    
    
    Set abc = Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn + x).End(xlDown)
    row2 = abc.Row
    col2 = abc.Column
    
    Range(Cells(row1, col1), Cells(row2, col2)).Select
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
   End If
Next x
I have a banner of 31 points, I have to search all the banner points less than 30 and replace the content of the column by -.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Column A

```
 Columns("a").cells.numberformat = "-"
```

Comment: You should at least note that this is cosmetic only and will not change any values in cells, which very well may be needed.